# Parsing JSON using Skyscanner JsonPath implementation in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm trying to use Skyscanner JsonPath implementation (ref. https://github.com/Skyscanner/JsonPath-PHP).

Following their instruction I've tried to make a little PHP sample (named testSkyScanner.php), in this way (I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 ....)

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    use JsonPath/JsonObject

    $theJson = '{
        "codiciColore": [{
            "id": 2,
            "descrizione": "Giallo",
            "rgb": "FFFF00",
            "priorita": 2,
            "situazionePazienti": {
                "numeroPazienti": 9,
                "numeroPazientiInVisita": 9,
                "mediaAttesa": "00:22",
                "numeroPazientiInAttesa": 0
            }
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "descrizione": "Verde",
            "rgb": "00FF00",
            "priorita": 3,
            "situazionePazienti": {
                "numeroPazienti": 16,
                "numeroPazientiInVisita": 9,
                "mediaAttesa": "03:03",
                "numeroPazientiInAttesa": 7
            }
        }]
   }';

   $jsonObject = new JsonObject();

?>
```

and I've organized my code in this way ...

[image]

When I try to execute it using `php testSkyScanner.php` I obtain this error ...

```
PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'JsonPath' has no effect in /var/www/html//Test/tmp/MyTestSkyScanner/testSkyScanner.php on line 7
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/Test/tmp/MyTestSkyScanner/testSkyScanner.php on line 7
```

Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'JsonPath' has no effect in /var/www/html//Test/tmp/MyTestSkyScanner/testSkyScanner.php on line 7
```

This error is telling you that

```
use JsonPath/JsonObject
```

doesn't achieve anything (and is also invalid, see below). There is no concept of "imported namespaces" in PHP. The **use** keyword is used to create aliases (helpful for long namespaces) but the fully qualified namespace must be provided when the class is used.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/Test/tmp/MyTestSkyScanner/testSkyScanner.php on line 7
```

Namespaces are separated using backslashes, not forward slashes, that's what is causing this error.

You should omit the "use" line altogether, and instead call:

```
$jsonObject = new JsonPath\JsonObject();
```

If you are using Composer, don't forget to require the composer autoload script at the top of your script:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: I've tried to comment the "use" line and use `$jsonObject = new JsonPath/JsonObject();` but obtain .... `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JsonPath' not found in /var/www/html/Test/tmp/MyTestSkyScanner/testSkyScanner.php on line 40` .... (I'm quite a newbie in PHP so sorry for the entry-level question .....)

Comment: Backslash, not forward slash - and have you actually require()'d or include()'d the module anywhere?

Comment: Did you use composer to get the library?  If so, you need to require the autoload file. I'll edit my answer to include this

Comment: Yes I've used composer ..... It's quite difficult for my PHP skill but now, with your replies, I've stuff to work on ....

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer works for you please remember to accept it. :)